# Add observables in a ngfor

Tags: angular

As I can add observables to the method `ConsultarTelefonos()` so that it charges only when they click on the telephone section.

I'm using modals to load the pop-up screen

**menu-pacientes.component.ts**

```
private telefonoPacienteLista: TelefonoInterface;

ConsultarTelefonos() {
  this.dataApiService.ListPatientsCellphone()
    .subscribe((
      data: TelefonoInterface) => {
      this.telefonoPacienteLista = data;
      console.log("Telefonos Cargados")
    }, error => this.mensajeError(error));
}
```

**menu-pacientes.component.html**

```
<ng-template #pacienteModal>
  <div  id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#t-gral">General</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-tel">Teléfono(s)</a></li> <!-- Here i want add it -->
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-antecedentes">Antecedentes</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-estudio">Estudio</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-consulta">Consulta</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-facturacion">Datos de Facturación</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: If you meant you want to call  ConsultarTelefonos()  on clicking Teléfono(s) use : (click)=" ConsultarTelefonos()". Hope this helps

Comment: MenuPacientesComponent.html:71 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: The problem, when I add the line, I mark the error that I added before. I understand that the problem is that the resource is not loaded yet so I wanted to use observables in that section.

Comment: Do you mean you need to display values from an observable in the list section